# How to know when to use "bon" or "bien"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, adjectifs, adverbes

Richard Harrison's comment here reminded me that when I started learning French (with any seriousness), I could never work out when to use *bon* and when to use *bien*.

In the end – as with a great deal of my French – I intuited it, which means I'm still incapable of explaining *why* I use one or the other.

Is it as simple as *good* and *well*?

Comment: *Bon* = adjective, *bien* = adverb. (plus a couple expressions, idioms and set locutions...)

Comment: Je dirais comme Dave, mais du coup l'expression "Il est bien, ce garçon" devrait être incorrecte.

Comment: @Joubarc: comme je disais, il y a pas mal d'expressions et idiomes qui sortent de cette définition grammaticale ("bien" comme adjectif, "bon" comme incise/interjection etc.). Mais ça couvre quand même 90% des cas...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well is definitively *bien*.

Good is *bon* in “*Ce gâteau est bon*”, “*Je suis bon*”.

But good is *bien* or *bon* in “This is good!” (*bon*: this taste good, this is cool, *bien*: this is cool, nice)

[This site](http://french.about.com/library/weekly/aa122200.htm) gives a table of possible meanings depending on the use.

```
            Bon     Bien    Mauvais    Mal
adjective   good    well    bad        wrong
adverb      nice    well    bad        badly
noun        form    good(s) bad part   evil
```

[Another page](http://french.about.com/library/weekly/aa122200b.htm) on this site gives examples of uses.

Comment: Bon (well), je suis un peu fatigué maintenant, mais c'est plus compliqué que ça.

Comment: Quelqu'un de bien. Bien fait pour toi. Il est bon/il est bien.

Comment: @Gilles : Would you mind expanding on that comment sometime ?

Answer (score 15):

#### Nouns

Un *bon*, is either:

- a voucher, ticket, or bond that grants access to something.
- the opposite of a bad guy (*les bons et les méchants*).

Un *bien*, is either:

- a possession, usually a material one like a good (or goods), but not only.
- or together with a definite article, *le bien* is also the opposite of the evil (*le mal*).

#### Interjections

Both *bon* and *bien* are interjections.

> Bon, vous avez fini ?
>
> Bien, vous avez fini ?

The former is rather deprecatory (*bon* ≈ *c'est bien beau tout ça, mais…*), whereas *bien* is basically the same as *alright*.

#### Adverbial and adjectival uses

*Bon* is an adjective. It qualifies a *noun* and is inflected accordingly.

> Une *bonne approche* requiert de *bons outils*.

*Bien* is an adverb, qualifies a *verb* (or an *adjective*, or another *adverb*) and cannot be inflected.

> Elle est *bien gentille*<sup>(adj.)</sup>, mais *bien souvent*<sup>(adv.)</sup> elle ne *formule*<sup>(v.)</sup> pas *bien* ses phrases.

Notice that *bien* can therefore qualify… *bon* :-)

> Ah elle est *bien bonne* celle là !

As for the translations, truly enough, *bon* as an adjective most often translates to “good”, even though with a definite article it would in most cases be translated with “right” (*C'est la bonne maison* – It's the right house). However, *bien* might be best translated with one of many adverbs. In the above examples it can be translated as *enough*, *quite*, *well*, *very*, but we could also mention *nicely*, *rightly*, *fairly*, *correctly*, *properly*, *rather*, and so on.

Also be careful that English provides only one comparative, namely *better* (since the old adverb *bet* fell into disuse), when French has two; the adjectival form is *meilleur(e)(s)*, and the adverbial form is *mieux*.

#### Delicate choice after specific verbs.

- A few set phrases involving *être*:

  > C'est bon/bien. (here *bon* stands for “ok” or “good”(taste) and *bien* for “nice”(not visually); and with a specific stress on *bon*, or with *trop bon*, it becomes slang for “fucking enjoyable”).
  >
  > Il serait bon/bien de… ('d better do it / 'd rather think about it)

  and a few grammatical constructions:

  > Elle est bien [cette maison].

  It means the same as “*Cette maison est bien*” (nice), but it has different connotations as “*C'est une bonne maison*” (well-made, resistant).

  > C'est bien qu'[il soit venu].

  This one can be compared with *c'est souvent que…* (*souvent* is also an adverb).
- State verbs (*être*, *paraitre*, *sembler*, etc.) may introduce an adjective as “*attribut du sujet*”, “*attribut du complément*”, or could themselves be qualified with an adverb.
  Sometimes common sense or experience is needed to disambiguate:

  > *Ça* semble *bon*. (here, *bon* ≈ *OK*)
  >
  > Il *semble bien*. (here, *sembler bien* ≈ *to “be likely indeed”*)
  >
  > Ça semble *bien peu*. (here, *bien peu* ≈ *not much*)

- With *faire*:

  > Il fait *bon* vivre. / Il est *bon vivant*.

  Notice here that *vivant* is used as a substantive, therefore the adjective *bon* is the one expected. Now, in “*bon vivre*” and in the following set phrase the substantive is somehow implicit (one could think of the “temperature” in the following):

  > Il fait *bon*.

  In comparison, in the next sentence, *il* can only refer to someone (it's a personal pronoun), and it is claimed that their actions were right.

  > Il *fait bien*.
- And also *sentir* and *tenir* (and probably a few others).

  > Ah ce fromage, il sent bien ! (Basically, it stinks.)
  >
  > Tu sens bon aujourd'hui. (To smell good, avoid using *bien* here…)

  The difference between *tenir bon* and *tenir bien* is only a matter of nuance, the former emphasizes endurance, whereas the latter is used in specific situations to ask to hold tight/firmly.