# Quelle est la différence entre meilleur et mieux ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, adverbes, comparatifs

Dans quelles situations peut-on utiliser ces mots ?

Y a-t-il une différence d'utilisation ou de sens entre ceux-ci ?

J'ai besoin d’exemples. S.V.P.

> Elle est ma meilleure amie.
>   Le meilleur tapis dans le monde est produit en Iran.
>   La météo en été est mieux que l'hiver.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Voir http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/446/how-to-know-when-to-use-bon-or-bien si c'est bien là la racine du problème c'est aussi peut-être la meilleure réponse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quelque chose de bon peut devenir meilleur, et lorsque quelque chose est bien, ça peut devenir mieux.

*Bon* et son comparatif associé *meilleur* sont des adjectifs, alors que *bien* et son comparatif associé *mieux* sont des adverbes.

À titre d'exemple, si on s'en tient à ce qu'autorise la grammaire, voici les deux formes acceptables pour la météo :

> La météo en été est meilleure qu'en hiver.
>
> La météo en été, c'est mieux qu'en hiver.

Mais ceci ne répond pas à la question intéressante qui contient des subtilités, à savoir, [qu'est-ce qui est bon et qu'est-ce qui est bien ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/446/how-to-know-when-to-use-bon-or-bien)