# Les Adverbes identiques à leur adjectif masculin singulier ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, adverbes

Cette figure est issue de la page 45 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar, 5e ed* de Mary Crocker. En dépit des fils tels que [How to know when to use "bon" or "bien"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/446/how-to-know-when-to-use-bon-or-bien), je reste désemparé. 
[image]

Par exemple, le verbe « sent » est qualifié comme réclamant un adverbe. Or, pourquoi pas :
« Ça sent bien » ou « Ça sent plus mauvais/pire » ?

D'ailleurs, pourquoi pas *chèrement*, *clairement*, *courtement*, *durement*, *faussement*, *fortement*, *hautement*, *justement*, *nettement* ?

J'ai tenté une recherche [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cela+sent+bien%2Ccela+sent+bon&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccela%20sent%20bien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccela%20sent%20bon%3B%2Cc0) et je m'aperçois d'un pic juste avant 1750.

Answer (score 5):

Les construction qui sont regroupées sous cette étiquette sont nombreuses et variées, pas toujours invariable, et peu de grammairiens les discutent en détails (voire incluent plus de 2 catégories!). Grevisse (*Le Bon Usage 14e ed.*, §963) y consacre pas moins de **8 pages**, je tenterai de résumer les différents cas rapidement:

- Adjectifs employés comme adverbes de degré (généralement usage régional ou familier, par ex. *tout plein*), pas nécessairement invariable.
- Épithète détachée du nom et rattachée au verbe (*tomber dru*, *servir chaud*, *claquer sec*), autre cas où la variabilité est légitime.
- Un grand nombre d'usages figés, où il est fréquent que l'adverbe en -ment ait acquis un sens plus métaphorique que l’adjectif correspondant (*voler bas/haut*, *filer doux*, *travailler dur*, *mettre bas*) voire n'existe pas (*arrêter court*), mais parfois existant en parallèle avec l'adverbe (*Chanter faux*, *parler franc*, *creuser profond*). Ce sont presque toujours des monosyllabique quoique la langue littéraire aime à improviser. Dans de nombreux cas, on imagine mal comment et pourquoi on pourrait accorder: *voir rouge*, *voter socialiste*, *penser écologique*...
- Des cas où l'adjectif remplace un complément adverbial obligatoire (*couter 200 euros -> couter cher*, *peser une tonne -> peser lourd*, *sentir la rose -> sentir bon*) ou un complément d'objet direct sous-entendu (*manger gras*).
- Élimination du *-ment* de manière plus ou moins généralisée dans les français populaires (quoique le degré de pénétration peut varier selon les mots et les régions): *attaché solide*, *rentrer direct chez soi*, *penser pareil*.
- Dérivés d'autres constructions et cas de certains adjectifs qui éliminent leurs adverbes: *exprès*, *même*, *soi-disant* (qui tient de nos jours plus de l'adjectif invariable et qu'on rencontre parfois accordé), *de proche en proche*, *soudain*, *vite*, *battant*...
- Cas de *juste* au sens de "précisément, exactement" (et non "droit", comme le traduit ce manuel) que pour une raison que je m'explique mal, Grevisse classe à part. Peut-être parce que son usage est beaucoup plus généralisé que celui des adjectifs figés? *Droit* a, en Suisse et au Québec (sous la forme *drette/drès*), un usage similaire qui remonte à l'ancien français.
- Autres expressions où la variabilités est possible: *tout rond*, *tout craché*, *heures tapant ou tapantes*...

La majorités des exemples ici se rattachent à la catégorie des usages figés ou des compléments adverbiaux, qu'il convient de comparer (à mon avis) aux verbes à particules de l'anglais: protester leur existence revient à se plaindre que les langues sont différentes...

Quant à la remarque concernant *sentir pire*, l'expression est (en ce qui me concerne) *parfaitement possible, mais incomplète*: en tant qu'adjectif de comparaison, il est plutôt inhabituel que *pire* s'emploie sans préciser *pire que quoi*, propriété qu'il ne perd pas lorsque son usage devient adverbial.

Answer (score 1):

Nuance sensorielle ou sentimentale :

> - *Cela sent **bon*** : mon nez perçoit des effluves agréables.
> - *Cela sent **bien***  : j'ai le sentiment de ...

"*Cela (ou ça) sent bien l'arnaque ici*" : j'ai l'impression que cette communication cherche à duper ses cibles, qui devient "*ça pue*" : j'exprime mon dégoût pour la situation.

Quant à parler, autant parler simplement : *elle voit clair* sera souvent employé parce que plus court que *elle voit clairement*, mais on aurait plutôt tendance à utiliser :

> - *Elle [y] voit **clair*** pour dire qu'elle a compris la situation pour elle même
> - *Elle voit **clairement** le jeu de son adversaire*, pour ce qui est à l'extérieur d'elle-même.

*Clairement* devient ici synonyme de *plus clair*, il augmente la clairvoyance