# Difference between "soudain" and "soudainement"?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, usage

*Soudain* seems to be used to mean *suddenly,* but then when should *soudainement* be used? I can't discern a clear difference in usage other than that *soudain* is more often at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: 2 erreurs: soudainement. soutenu (masculin)

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina merci, en effet tu as raison.

Comment: Don’t know if this applies to French “linking/state-of-being verbs” (hence the comment), but in English it’s argued that such verbs can’t really be “modified” by adverbs at all & that adverbs used in sentences with them are actually modifying those verbs’ predicate adjectives/complements. IF this is the case in French, MAYBE when the notion of “suddenly” is used with French’s equivalent of “linking/state-of-being verbs” to modify, not the copula itself, but its predicate adjective, “soudainement” COULD be (somewhat ironically, if so) the preferred form: “Il est/deviens **soudainement fou**.”

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: You should first understand the answer of guillaume girod-vitouchkina: *soudain* can be either an adjective or an adverb while *soudainement* is always an adverb. The following assumes that the question only makes sense if *soudain* and *soudainement* are used as adverbs.

---

At first, I would have said, following [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/soudain/73593/synonyme), that *soudain* and *soudainement* are synonyms (when *soudain* is used as an adverb of course), and in fact you probably won't notice much difference between the two definitions in one dictionary ([a](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soudain), [a'](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soudainement); [b](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/soudain), [b'](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/soudainement)).

But, there is still a subtle difference: the *[Encylopédie Universelle](http://encyclopedie_universelle.fracademic.com/69450/soudainement)* gives a hint at the right answer:

> Alors que soudain (adv.) désigne la brusquerie, la rapidité d'un fait, soudainement caractérise la manière dont l'action se déroule.
>
> While *soudain* (used as an adverb) expresses the abruptness, the quickness of an event, *soudainement* characterises the way the action unfolds.

A longer answer (going in the same direction) is given [here](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2499) by the *Office québécois de la langue française*:

> Employé comme adverbe, soudain signifie « tout à coup, subitement » et sert à marquer le fait qu’une chose survient sans signe avant-coureur, d’un seul mouvement. / As an adverb, *soudain* means "all of a sudden" and is used to note that something happens without forerunner.
>
> L’adverbe soudainement est dérivé de l’adjectif soudain. Il signifie « d’une manière rapide et imprévue » et caractérise une action qui se déroule d’une manière brusque et inattendue. / The adverb *soudainement* is derived from the adjective *soudain*. It means "in a swift and unforeseen manner" and characterises an action that unfolds in an abrupt and unexpected way.
>
> En résumé, on emploie l’adverbe soudain pour désigner la brusquerie, la rapidité d’un fait et on emploie l’adverbe soudainement pour caractériser la manière brusque, inattendue avec laquelle une action se déroule. / Finally, *soudain* is employed to denote the abruptness, the swiftness of an event while the adverb *soudainement* is used to characterise the abrupt and unexpected manner an action unfolds.

But the most important point for you may be the conclusion: in practice there are a lot of sentences where you can use one for the other although you will probably use *soudainement* less often in standard speech (it is more formal).

> Toutefois, dans certains cas, la nuance entre ces deux adverbes peut s’avérer ténue et les mots soudain et soudainement deviennent pratiquement interchangeables, bien que l’emploi de soudain paraisse parfois plus littéraire, surtout lorsqu’il est employé après le verbe.

---

Examples (from [here](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2499)):

- Use of *soudain*

  > Soudain, l’enfant réapparut, ne se doutant pas que tous l’avaient désespérément cherché.
  >
  > Je lisais tranquillement quand soudain une branche est tombée sur le toit de la maison.
- Use of *soudainement*

  > Vers la fin du mois de février, elle est tombée soudainement malade.
  >
  > Elle entra soudainement dans le café, croyant y avoir aperçu son amie.
  >
  > Des dizaines de pigeons quittèrent soudainement le toit sur lequel ils étaient perchés.
- Use of one or the other

  > Le vent s’est mis soudain à souffler très fort / Le vent s’est mis soudainement à souffler très fort.
  >
  > À l’annonce de cette nouvelle, sa joie se transforma soudain en inquiétude / À l’annonce de cette nouvelle, sa joie se transforma soudainement en inquiétude.

(All the translations are mine, please correct them if needed!)

Comment: Soudainement cannot be an adjective.

Comment: @user2987828 See EDIT at the beginning of the post.

Answer (score 12):

Soudain peut être soit adjectif soit adverbe :

> Un phénomène soudain ...
>
> Soudain, il se leva ...

D'autres emplois (quasiment inusités aujourd'hui) [existent](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soudain):

- *tout soudain* (*aussitôt*) attesté en 1541 : *Et, tout soudain, une clameur sauvage: « iaha! » le signal! le signal! la chasse est ouverte!*
- *en soudain*  (*promptement, aussitôt*)
- *soudain que (aussitôt que)*

On peut supposer que la construction adverbiale *tout soudain*, s'est transformée, par simplicité, en *soudain*.

Soudainement est un adverbe dérivé de soudain, attesté au XIIème siècle (comme *fréquemment* de *fréquent*, *irrémédiablement* de *irrémédiable*, et de manière presque automatique pour n'importe quel adjectif - sauf quelques exceptions - etc.). Il est **moins employé**, surtout à l'oral. Le sens est quasiment équivalent:

> Le moteur s'arrêta soudainement (ou soudain).

à noter que soudain a la même origine latine que subit (subitus), qui est un synonyme, et qui a donné comme adverbe subitement.

Comme très souvent, la simplicité et la concision l'emportent à l'oral.

En ce qui concerne **les formes identiques pour l'adjectif et l'adverbe**, on trouvera des explications sur ce [post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8228/les-adverbes-identiques-%C3%A0-leur-adjectif-masculin-singulier). A noter que des adjectifs/adverbes autonomes (en dehors de constructions, sans être attachés à des verbes), sont assez peu nombreux au 6ème paragraphe de ce post : *juste, même, exprès, vite* . *justement* et *expressément* existent encore.

Comment: Confirmé par le Ngram : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soudain%2Csoudainement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoudain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoudainement%3B%2Cc0

Comment: But can you give examples of when to use *soudainement* ?

Comment: Both top answers extremely good, mostly gave him the bounty because you already had 4k rep and he didn't. :D spreading the wealth

Comment: @Aerovistae. Soudainement est beaucoup plus littéraire. "Il est arrivé si soudainement que j'en suis tombée de ma chaise." Ou: "Il est arrivé soudainement, sans prévenir". L'emploi de soudain/soudainement semble dépendre de l'effet qu'on veut produire dans un récit: Soudain, il est arrivé sans prévenir. Soudain il s'est mis à pleuvoir = Il s'est mis à pleuvoir soudainement.

Answer (score 4):

"Soudainement" is an adverb.
"Soudain" can be either an adverb or an adjective.

When you need an adjective, you have to use "soudain", whereas it is an epithete or an attribute:

> Un fracas soudain me sortit de ma torpeur.
>
> Je ne sais pas quoi répondre, tout cela est si soudain !

When you need to qualify a verb, you have to use "soudainement":

> Mon ordinateur s'éteignit soudainement.

When you need an adverb to put "en incise" as a a circumstantial complement, you can use "soudain" or "soudainement". However, "soudain" is more used.

> Soudain, mon ordinateur s'éteignit.
>
> Soudainement, mon ordinateur s'éteignit.

Comment: *Precise* is not a verb in English :) The word you want is *qualify.*

Answer (score 2):

Usage might be slightly different between French and English, but "soudain" is equivalent to "sudden", while "soudainement" is equivalent to "suddenly".

It's one of the rare occurrences where French might more concise than English: "All of a sudden" would be properly translated by "Soudain".

Comment: [Soudain l'été dernier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soudain_l'%C3%A9t%C3%A9_dernier_%28film%29) was a very good translation of the play by T. Williams. "Suddenly" will be translated by *soudain* most of the time.

Comment: Yes, so I've gathered, but then when *should* "soudainement" be used?

Comment: @Aerovistae voila !

Comment: @Laure Hi. With the verb "disparaître", which of the two do you think I should use: "***disparaître soudain or soudainement***"? If I go by the answers given, both seem to work in this instance.

Comment: @Alone-zee I'd say *disparaître soudainement* would refer to the manner in which one disappears, *disparaître soudain* would refer to the act itself. *Soudain, il disparu* (All of a sudden, he disappeared) vs *il  disparu soudainement* (he disappeared suddenly).

Answer (score 1):

As Anne Aunyme said, "*soudain*" can be either an adverb or an adjective, meanwhile "*soudainement*" is the adverb constructed with "*soudain*" taken as adjective.

In the case of both adverbs, we use them differently:

"*Soudain*" is the equivalent of "*tout à coup*" , which "*soudainement*" is not: In fact, we use "*soudain*" generally at the beginning of a proposition, to mark that the suddenness of the action is most striking, and we'll use "*soudainement*" at the end of the proposition when it is just a secondary precision qualifying the manner of the action rather than the surprise it may cause.

So, in literature, you generally won't find "*soudain*" at the end of the proposition when it has the value of an adverb, but you can nevertheless find it at the end if it is an adjective:

"*Je fus surpris par son appel soudain*" (adjective)

"*Soudain, le vase tomba*" (adverb)

"*Le vase tomba soudainement*" (adverb)

"*Soudain, le vase tomba*" emphazises the surprise caused by the fall of the vase, meanwhile "*le vase tomba soudainement*"  is only a cool observation of the suddenness of the event.