# Peut-on dire « un peu meilleur » or « un peu pire » ? Sinon, quelle est la bonne expression ?

Tags: grammaire, comparatifs

Je ne suis pas locuteur natif de français. Une amie m'a dit que ces deux expressions sont des anglicismes. En anglais on peut dire « *a bit better* » ou « *a bit worse* » pour une comparaison de degré limité. Je pense que les comparaisons pareilles avec les autres adjectifs sont permises, e.g. « un peu plus large ».

Est-ce que les courtes formes comparatives sont distinguées à cette façon dans la syntaxe française ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« Un peu meilleur » est correct. « Un peu pire » devrait aussi l'être, mais en genéral on utilise soit « un peu moins bon » soit « un peu plus mauvais », je ne sais pas exactement pour quelle raison<sup>1</sup>.

L'anglicisme dont parle ton amie est probablement lié aux circonstances dans lesquelles il est possible d'utiliser de telles comparaisons. Notamment pour dire « It's better like this » à propos de la situation actuelle, il faut dans ce cas utiliser « C'est mieux comme ça ». C'est la même différence que  [Bon vs Bien](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/446/how-to-know-when-to-use-bon-or-bien).

—
<sup>1. *Pire* est généralement plus insistant que *moins bon*, ce qui a un effet opposé à *un peu*, et c'est probablement pour cela que les deux ne sont pas utilisés ensemble.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

En France, dire "*un peu meilleur*" ou "*un peu pire*" sera compris par votre interlocuteur.
Toutefois, "*un peu pire*" est peut-être moins (voire pas) utilisé, j'utiliserais plutôt "*un peu moins bon*" ou "*un peu moins bien*" selon le contexte.

"*Un peu meilleur*" est communément utilisé, il existe aussi "*un peu mieux*", que j'utiliserais dans un contexte moins formel.

Comment: Ça n'a rien à voir avec la formalité. *Un peu mieux* c'est un adverbe, *un peu meilleur* c'est un adjectif. Quand il est possible d'utiliser les deux, le sens est différent.

Comment: Exact, cependant, dans un contexte plus formel, je préférerais utiliser "un peu meilleur" à "un peu mieux". Mais cela reste subjectif. :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Dans "C'est un peu mieux", _mieux_ n'est pas un adverbe je crois.

Comment: @biozic: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mieux

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Adjectif invariable, d'après ce lien.

Comment: @biozic: Reste que ça n'as pas le même sens (ou usage). La confiture n'est pas « mieux ». Et on ne dit pas « la situation a changé, c'est meilleur qu'avant ».