# Using "mieux" to compare two nouns

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes

"This chair is better than that chair."

The canonical translation for "better" as an adjective would be "meilleur".

> Cette chaise est meilleur que celle-là.

But would "mieux" also work?

> Cette chaise est **mieux** que celle-là.

What if the sentence is "This chair is *much* better than that chair"? Would either "beaucoup meilleur" or "beaucoup mieux" work?

> Cette chaise est beaucoup meilleur/mieux que celle-là.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "cette chaise est mieux que celle là" works.

"Beaucoup meilleur" is never correct. Always use "beaucoup mieux" instead.

However, "bien meilleur" is correct and is somewhat more formal than "beaucoup mieux".

Comment: Also note that since a chair is feminine, you need to agree "*meilleur*" into "*meilleure*", in the feminine ("*Cette chaise est **bien meilleure** que celle-là.*"). *Mieux* is invariable.

Answer (score 2):

*Mieux* is an adverb, comparative of "bien" (also an adverb).

*Meilleur(e)* is an adjective, comparative of "bon" (also  an adjective)

Both *bien* and *bon* translate as "good" in English but [there's a difference](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/446/82).

"*Cette chaise est mieux que celle là*" is not correct. It's commonly used in spoken language because it's shorter but you shouldn't write it down. We tend to use "*mieux*" especially at the end of the sentence : "*Cette chaise est bien mieux*" (This chair is much better). You should say "*Cette chaise est bien meilleure.*"

So to sum up :

> Cette chaise est **meilleure** que celle là

(This chair is better than that one : adjective)

(Don't forget to add an "e" when it's feminine ! (**une** chaise))

> Il nage **mieux** que l'année dernière

(He swims better than last year : adverb)

And as it has been said : always "**bien** meilleur", and you can say "**beaucoup** mieux" or "**bien** mieux".

And of course, "best" is always "*meilleur(e)*"

**EDIT :** Acutally *Mieux* can be used as an adjective. It's used instead of *meilleur* when there is no noun directly after it :

> Il est en **meilleure** santé

(He's in better health)

> Il va **mieux**.

(He's feeling better/ he's better)

Turns out "*mieux*" can also be a noun... I'm sorry that French can be so confusing ! But it's the same rule as  above : if there is a noun directly after use *meilleur*, if not use *mieux*.

> Je m'attendais à **mieux**

(I expected better)

> Je m'attendais à un **meilleur** film

(I expected a better movie)

Comment: Incroyable, je n'avais jamais réalisé qu'utiliser *mieux* comme adjectif était une erreur.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps encore faudrait-il que ce soit une erreur. « Cette chaise est bien mais celle là est mieux » est tout à fait correct. « Cette chaise est bonne mais celle là est meilleure » est possible aussi.

Comment: @jlliagre je pense justement (comme Simon je crois) que c'est une erreur qui est passée dans le langage courant à force.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Non, « mieux » est attesté en tant qu'adjectif depuis le douxième siècle (*melz*). Littré: *Mieux se prend quelquefois adjectivement (d'autant plus facilement, que melius n'est que le neutre de melior), et signifie meilleur, plus convenable, plus propre à la chose dont il s'agit. Il n'y a rien de mieux, rien n'est mieux que ce que vous dites.* Aussi: http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic37742-mieux-peutil-etre-adjectif.html

Comment: @TeleportingGoat en fait je ne m'étais jamais posé la question avant que tu en parles.

Answer (score -1):

"Meilleur" is more like "best". You can't use "beaucoup meilleur" like you can't use "more best". French use "**bien mieux**" for much better, as in english actually

Comment: "Meilleur" does not only mean "best" : "*J'ai des meilleures notes cette année*" "I have better grades this year"