# Placing "mieux" in front of noun

Tags: adverbes, comparatifs

I posted a [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22286/using-mieux-to-compare-two-nouns) asking whether one can use *mieux* in the sentence "Cette chaise est mieux que celle-là" and got two different answers, one saying that it's fine, the other saying that it's incorrect and should not be used in written language. So it seems that this is up for debate.

What about if we were to place *mieux* in front of a noun?

> J'ai une **mieux** chaise que tu as.

Is this unambiguously wrong? Should *meilleure* always be used here?

Comment: This  has [already been answered](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/22294/358) by  @TeleportingGoat who wrote:   "*Mieux*" can be used as an adjective. It's used instead of *meilleur* when there is **no noun directly after it**".  In your sentence you have the noun a *chaise* directly after *mieux*, and it is wrong.

Comment: The answer you accepted in the other question was originally incorrect and is now self contradicting. The debate should be closed now: using *mieux* as an adjective has always be possible in French although with restrictions about its location in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is unambiguously wrong.

In my opinion, the best sentence would be:

> J'ai une **meilleure** chaise que **toi**.