# Difference between "il est bon" and "il est bien"

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes

> Il est (bon/bien) de manger des légumes regulièrement.
>
> Il est (bon/bien) de vous avoir rencontré.

Should we use "il est bon" or "il est bien" in these two sentences? I've read about the [differences](https://frenchtogether.com/bien-bon/) between *bon* and *bien*, and but I don't think it covers this expression.

Comment: There are already several questions on [*bon* vs *bien* on French Language](http://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=bon+bien), [this answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/6505/358) seems to cover your question.

Comment: I would not trust the article you link to. For the record, the article you link to says   « C’est bon comme ça ? » but I expect most French people would say « Ça va comme ça ? ».

Comment: Maybe you can help me get answer for [this meta question](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/634/learners-how-often-do-you-ask-a-new-question-vs-how-often-you-find-your-answer)

Comment: @Laure You mean this part? "C'est bon/bien. (here bon stands for “ok” or “good”(taste) and bien for “nice”(not visually); and with a specific stress on bon, or with trop bon, it becomes slang for “fucking enjoyable”)." I think it doesn't cover my question that well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Il est bien de` sound very strange to me in both case and in general. So I would go with `il est bon de` in both case.

However, `il est bon de` is very uncommon. The only sentence I can remember with `il est bon` is a song based on a Bible translation from the 1870s...

You would use `C'est bon`/`C'est bien` in modern French. In this regard, the subtle difference is that `c'est bon` means it is good to somebody or for something specific, while `c'est bien` is good in a more general sens. For example, you would say

> C'est **bien** de trier les déchets

because sorting your wastes is inherently a good thing and this is what you want to stress. However, you would say

> C'est **bon** pour la planète de trier les déchets

if you want to stress that it is good for a specific object, here planet earth.

So to answer your question:

> C'est **bon** de manger des légumes régulièrement

Means that it is good to you, for your health.

> C'est **bien** de manger des légumes régulièrement

Means that it is good in general, for example because it is more ecological than meat, etc...

> C'est **bon** de vous avoir rencontré

Means that you fell good meeting this person. You would say this, for example, if you felt down, met someone and that person cheered you up.

> C'est **bien** de vous avoir rencontré

Means it is a good thing *beyond the scope of you two*. For example, your meeting will lead to a promising collaboration on a important projects.

Answer (score 0):

That article doesn't cover it all, indeed.

There are many cases in which both can be used, usually "*bon*" is more dated and formal than "*bien*" in that case (only when you can use both!).

Here it means different things, but all four are correct.

On a different topic, casually you'll often use "*c'est*" instead of "*il est*" here,  but it's still correct.

> Il est bon de manger des légumes

It is wise to eat vegetables. If you say "*c'est bon*" here it means "it tastes good to eat vegetables"

> Il est bien de manger des légumes

Here it means that same with "*c'est*". It means it's a good thing, it's very close to the other but there's a slight difference in tone.

> Il est bon de vous rencontrer

It feels good to meet you, it's a nice experience.

> Il est bien de vous rencontrer

It's a good thing (for my career or the project) the meet you. I wouldn't use this one.

---

Another thing, if you see old friends or family you hadn't see in a while, you might want to say "It's good to see you". You could say :

> Qu'il est bon de vous voir

If you're Gandalf. Now we would say something like :

> Ça fait du bien de vous voir

Note that there are a lot of missing cases in your article, it's not as simple as they say it is. For instance, "*un bon*" is indeed a voucher but "*une bonne*" is a maid/servant.