# Utilisation de « bien » et « bon » pour une personne

Tags: expressions, adjectifs, adverbes

Je n'ai jamais été sûre de ça et enfin j'aimerais bien savoir comment utiliser correctement « bien » et « bon ».

Je suis en train de regarder une série en Netflix et une femme dit :

> Vous êtes vraiment quelqu'un de bon.

Mais dans les sous-titres il est écrit :

> Vous êtes vraiment quelqu'un de bien.

Mes questions sont :

1. Est-ce que les deux sont corrects ici ?
2. Est-ce qu'il y a beaucoup de situations où on peut les échanger ?
3. Est-qu'il y a un pense-bête qui aide à se souvenir de l'utilisation correcte ?

Comment: Related https://french.stackexchange.com/q/446/4134

Comment: Je suis abonné et *accro* à Netflix, mais je déplore la mauvaise qualité et l'incohérence de leurs sous-titres voire de leurs traductions. Ne prenez pas les sous-titres Netflix comme une référence... Les traductions pour les doublages et les sous-titres semblent parfois avoir été faits par des traducteurs de compétences bien inégales...

Answer (score 2):

On peut percevoir une subtile nuance:

*Quelqu'un de bon* est quelqu'un qui se démarque par sa *bonté*, dans le sens de *générosité*: quelqu'un qui est altruiste, qui est prêt à partager son temps, son argent, etc.

*Quelqu'un de bien* est quelqu'un qui se distingue par des qualités personnelles et/ou morales plus larges que la bonté: cette personne est quelqu'un qui par exemple est honnête, franc, sur qui on peut compter, qui respecte ses engagements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**I** Il y a une erreur dans les sous-titres.

Non, ce sont deux mots de significations différentes. Lorsqu'utilisé en parlant d'une personne, « bon » signifie « qui a pour les gens, et même les bêtes,  des intentions résultant pour eux en un plus grand bien-être, un plus grand pouvoir de jouir des biens matériels et intellectuels (pour les gens…)¹ et en plus de cela, qui est capables d'actions répondant à ces intentions » ; « bien » a un sens différent bien que connecté à celui de « bon » et dépendant des personnes qui l'utilisent ; « être bien » signifie pour beaucoup de monde tout d'abord avoir des réactions et le comportement de quelqu'un qui est bon mais certaines personnes n'insistent pas sur cet aspect du sens ; ce que tout le monde reconnait comme étant bien c'est la possession par une personne de certains standards de comportement, en particulier dans leur interaction avec leurs semblables, la possession de certains standards de façon de penser, d'habillement, de politesse qui les classe dans une catégorie sociale  jugée au dessus de celle de leurs contemporains, cela évidemment parce que ces standards sont relativement jugés souhaitables ;  il faut cependant comprendre que sur ce plan-là ce qui pour certaines personnes contribue à la qualité d'être bien n'est rien de spécial pour d'autre ; c'est donc une qualité toute relative ; la définition des standards est impossible ; personne n'a les mêmes standard, on ne peut que les situer dans la région vague de ce qui est plus ou moins idéal.

**II** On  peut utiliser « bien » à la place de bon (selon le point de vue de la définition que je donne des deux mots ci-dessus) et alors ce sera un euphémisme, pas si inhabituel de nos jours, où une certaine pudibonderie exècre la mention de la bonté du prochain ;  cependant il n'est pas question de l'inverse : on ne peut pas dire « bon » pour « bien ».

**III** Non, il ne semble pas qu'il existe de pense-bête pour cela mais vous pouvez toujours vous en faire un bien que rien ne remplace la lecture ; vous pourriez vous dire par exemple « bon chez les mendiants, bien chez les politiciens », mais je ne sais pas si c'est une si bonne idée.

¹<sub>On parlait en Grande Bretagne il y a quelques années d'instituer une certaine charte des droits des gorilles.</sub>